# Packet ID 104 threw when setting a potion effect packet

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Code:

```
PacketContainer hideplayer = new PacketContainer(PacketType.Play.Server.ENTITY_EFFECT);
        hideplayer.getIntegers().write(0, player.getEntityId());
        hideplayer.getBytes().write(0, (byte) 14);
        hideplayer.getBytes().write(1, (byte) 1);
        hideplayer.getIntegers().write(1, 1);
```

I am now setting a packetcontainer according to the wiki.vg, a wiki for protocollib
But when I send this packet, it kicks the player
(using Protocollib in Bukkit)

```
[00:26:11 ERROR]: Packet encoding of packet ID 104 threw (skippable? false)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find id for 'null' in map Registry[ResourceKey[minecraft:root / minecraft:mob_effect] (Stable)]
        at net.minecraft.network.FriendlyByteBuf.writeId(FriendlyByteBuf.java:140) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ClientboundUpdateMobEffectPacket.write(ClientboundUpdateMobEffectPacket.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.PacketEncoder.encode(PacketEncoder.java:41) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-371]
        at net.minecraft.network.PacketEncoder.encode(PacketEncoder.java:14) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-371]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107) ~[netty-codec-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:792) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:120) ~[netty-codec-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1020) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:311) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at com.comphenix.protocol.injector.netty.channel.NettyChannelProxy.writeAndFlush(NettyChannelProxy.java:227) ~[ProtocolLib (1).jar:?]
        at com.comphenix.protocol.injector.netty.channel.NettyChannelProxy.writeAndFlush(NettyChannelProxy.java:233) ~[ProtocolLib (1).jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.Connection.doSendPacket(Connection.java:459) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.Connection.lambda$sendPacket$11(Connection.java:433) ~[?:?]
        at com.comphenix.protocol.injector.netty.channel.NettyEventLoopProxy.lambda$proxyRunnable$2(NettyEventLoopProxy.java:48) ~[ProtocolLib (1).jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.82.Final.jar:4.1.82.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
[00:26:11 INFO]: LorkLork5487 lost connection: Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find id for 'null' in map Registry[ResourceKey[minecraft:root / minecraft:mob_effect] (Stable)]
```